# Does Google provide premium AdSense accounts?

Tags: google-adsense

An AdSense expert told me that Google provides premium AdSense accounts after qualifying with a few thousands page views per month.

I am using AdSense on my site, which is a Government Jobs alert website in India having 9k page views daily. Would I qualify for a premium AdSense account in this case?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, the qualifications are (approx):

> 5 million search queries, or 20 million content page views per month.

Other criteria is also at play, such as the general quality of your website and how original your content is. i.e. Inclusion is based on Google's perception of your website's reputation.

Unfortunately, you can't apply to become a premium publisher, as this is an invite-only thing. Google will offer to include you in the program if they feel as though your site meets their criteria.

Comment: Do you have a source for your quote?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Those seem to be the figures that are regularly bandied around on forum topics and blogs, etc. I found the above quote on a similar question on the Adsense product forums. Unfortunately, because it is invite-only, I don't think that it is as simple as "reach x amount of pageviews".

Answer (score 0):

The 20 mill page views and 5 mill searches aren't requirements. It all levels down to what Google see has a good market for them.If there are hundreds of a particular niche sites that has Premium access and it's competitive Google will be more restrictive of their choice. While a less competitive Niche that's performing well, regardless of the page views will get accepted. This is prominent in the Tech Field